# input time checking if empty jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Why this code is not working ? Even if I fill the input time is triggering alert('empty')

```
<label for="">New ETA:</label>
   <input type="time" class="neweta">
   <input type="button" onclick="newetasave(this)" value="save"></br>

function newetasave(t){
 var tr = $(t).closest('tr').prev()
 var neweta = $(t).prev('input').val()

 if ($(neweta).val("")) {
   alert('empty')

 }else {
   alert('not empty')
// $(tr).find('.eta').text(neweta)
 }
}
```

Comment: I've also tried with if($(neweta).val().lenght == 0).... but same result

Comment: `neweta` is not a jquery object and `$(neweta).val("")` doesn't get the input value, it sets it.
You need to have a look at the jQuery documentation.

Comment: so how to check if an input time is empty ? thank you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incomplete, i strongly recommend going through the jQuery documentation first.

Your code needs to be something like this:

```js
function newetasave(t){
 var tr = $(t).closest('tr').prev();
 var neweta = $(t).prev('input'); //Now its a jquery object

 if ($(neweta).val().length == 0) {
   alert('empty');

 }else {
   alert('not empty')
// $(tr).find('.eta').text(neweta)
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="">New ETA:</label>
   <input type="time" class="neweta">
   <input type="button" onclick="newetasave(this)" value="save"></br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just Javascript without passing by Jquery if you want

Try This

```
<label for="">New ETA:</label>
<input type="time" class="neweta">
<input type="button" onclick="newetasave()" value="save"></br>

 function newetasave(){
        var time=document.getElementsByClassName("neweta");
        console.log(time[0].value);
         if (time[0].value=="") {
                alert('empty')                  
            }else 
            {
                alert('not empty')
            }
    }
```